# D7 cron - Ajax getting cached by Varnish?

Tags: 7, cron

Somehow it never occurred to me that D7's cron is really a "poorman's cron" until I came across this [previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/running-cron-without-crontab).

The Ajax added to a user's page requests shouldn't impact the load time of the page.
However, Google's "Page Speed" is measuring the browser load times and it can inflate your numbers. For example, I came across a request that took 80 seconds and it was reported in "Google Analytics - Site Speed".

Since I'm running Varnish isn't there also a chance that pages with the Ajax get cached an then each subsequent page requests will run cron? That would explain the "Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running." error messages I'm often seeing.

I now switched to an external cron service (can't setup crontab on Pantheon).

Comment: Not directly on point, but I've used Elysia Cron on Pantheon with Drupal 6, and then just set up another site that has a crontab to run wget -O - -q -t 1 .../cron.php?cron_key=... once a minute with reasonable success.

Comment: I'm using Elysia Cron, too, great improvement over the regular cron